# How can I turn the output of asp:SiteMapPath into a list?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm extremely unfamiliar with both .NET and VB.NET and can't quite figure out how to do this. Say I have code like this:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server"></asp:SiteMapPath>
</div>
```

It outputs a bunch of `<span>`s with `>` as separators, something like this:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
  <span id="ctl00_SiteMapPath1">
    <a href="#ctl00_SiteMapPath1_SkipLink">
      <img alt="Skip Navigation Links" height="0" width="0" src="/Bonfield/WebResource.axd?d=PEpmmIw6qvhaEC3hEwXGjgvJKlzc3DOMu_e-zW-n6pfl6YR-iYjwmlvrYPb689EslKxysA7aoh_x_ALjLs5QXiz7NG41&amp;t=634245478914809245" style="border-width:0px;" />
    </a>
    <span>
      <a href="/Bonfield/Default.aspx">Home</a>
    </span>
    <span> &#187; </span>
    <span>Showcase</span><a id="ctl00_SiteMapPath1_SkipLink"></a></span>
</div>
```

How can I turn that into a list like:

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Showcase</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have solved this by now but you could use this function to loop through all the items in the rootnode of a sitemap and their descendants and build up a nested list.

You can remove `If item.HasChildNodes Then sb.Append(ListChildNodes(item))` if you are only interested in the top level

```
 Public Function SiteMap() As String
        Return ListChildNodes(System.Web.SiteMap.RootNode)
    End Function

    Private Function ListChildNodes(ByVal node As System.Web.SiteMapNode) As String
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

        sb.Append("<ul>")
        For Each item As SiteMapNode In node.ChildNodes
            sb.Append(String.Concat("<li><a href=""", item.Url, """>", item.Title, "</a></li>"))
            If item.HasChildNodes Then sb.Append(ListChildNodes(item))
        Next
        sb.Append("</ul>")

        Return sb.ToString
    End Function
```

For those who would like the C# version:

```
public string SiteMap()
        {
            return ListChildNodes(System.Web.SiteMap.RootNode);
        }
        private string ListChildNodes(System.Web.SiteMapNode node)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            sb.Append("<ul>");
            foreach (SiteMapNode item in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Concat("<li><a href=\"", item.Url, "\">", item.Title, "</a></li>"));
                if (item.HasChildNodes)
                    sb.Append(ListChildNodes(item));
            }
            sb.Append("</ul>");

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Then in your code you can just call to output the string to the page.

```
<h1>Site Map</h1>
    <%=SiteMap()%>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great except, everything in the node shows up :/

Answer (score 2):

While you can't get rid of the span tags, you CAN accomplish what you want. I ran into this same issue because I was using a purchased CSS/HTML site template the client wanted, but the entire thing was based on `<ul>`'s and `<li>`'s. Refactoring the CSS would have been too painful, so I found this solution that worked well without any changes to the CSS code.

You'll do two things:

1. Override the default Node template with one that uses `<li>` tags
2. Wrap the whole thing in a `<ul>` tag

Here's an example:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
  <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" >
    <NodeTemplate>
      <li>
        <a href='<%# Eval("url") %>' title='<%# Eval("description") %>'><%# Eval("title") %></a>
      </li>
    </NodeTemplate>
  </asp:SiteMapPath>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't have any means of testing this anymore, but if that works it would've been perfect for my needs.

Comment: Not Working, it will render the li inside a span

Comment: While a little involved, you CAN get rid of the spans. Have a look at my answer to this question, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of is putting you sitemap into a `<asp:menu>` control. This will however output as an html table, but visually it will show up a list:

```
<asp:Menu ID="leftNavigation" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" 
       StaticDisplayLevels="1" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1">
</asp:Menu>
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
```

Play around with all the styling and formatting options to get your desired output. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6ws38fw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for a detailed walkthrough.

Oh, and of course you could also look into using a treeview with a sitemap instead (see the same page).

Answer (score 0):

While a little involved, this is a solution that actually removes the spans and renders a clean list.

First, get rid of those excess spans by modifying the `SiteMapPath`. I have derived a class `NakedSiteMapPath` that does this. It still allows the usage of explicit spans in templates, if needed:

```
/// <summary>
///     A SiteMapPath, that does not render span elements.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
///     To still allow explizit spans inside the node templates, immediately prefix the opening and closing span elements
///     with the literal
///     prefix "<!--KEEP NEXT SPAN-->" (without the double quotes)
///     Example:
///     <code>
///     <PathSeparatorTemplate><!--KEEP NEXT SPAN--><span class="icon icon--greater"><!--KEEP NEXT SPAN--></span>
///         </PathSeparatorTemplate>
/// </code>
///     Those spans (opening and closing) will be kept, but the prefix removed in the rendered output.
/// </remarks>
/// <devdoc>
///     The MSDN doc has a nice example about a customized breadcrumb with a dropdown menu here:
///     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
/// </devdoc>
[AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:NakedSiteMapPath runat=server></{0}:NakedSiteMapPath>")]
public class NakedSiteMapPath : SiteMapPath {
    /// <summary>
    ///     Outputs server control content to a provided <see cref="T:System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" /> object and stores
    ///     tracing information about the control if tracing is enabled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The <see cref="T:System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" /> object that receives the control content.</param>
    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        //Render to a local string, then remove all unnecessary spans
        StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        TextWriter myTextWriter = new StringWriter(myStringBuilder);
        HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(myTextWriter);
        base.RenderControl(myWriter);

        string html = myStringBuilder.ToString();

        //Remove all spans, except those opening and closing spans wich have been marked with the literal comment "<!--KEEP NEXT SPAN-->"
        const string matchOpenExceptSkipPrefix = @"(?<!\<\!--KEEP NEXT SPAN--\>)<span>";
        const string matchCloseExceptSkipPrefix = @"(?<!\<\!--KEEP NEXT SPAN--\>)</span>";
        html = Regex.Replace(html, matchOpenExceptSkipPrefix, String.Empty);
        html = Regex.Replace(html, matchCloseExceptSkipPrefix, String.Empty);
        html = html.Replace(@"<!--KEEP NEXT SPAN-->", String.Empty);

        //finally, write the naked html out.
        writer.Write(html);
    }
}
```

With that, the spans are gone. To have custom links, like the `li` elements, you will need to use the templates, as others already have proposed. Here's an example ASPX page part with the `NakedSiteMapPath`:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="pagebreadcrumbs">
    <my:NakedSiteMapPath runat="server"
        PathDirection="RootToCurrent"
        RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="False">
        <PathSeparatorTemplate><!--KEEP NEXT SPAN--><span class="icon icon--greater"><!--KEEP NEXT SPAN--></span></PathSeparatorTemplate>
        <CurrentNodeTemplate>
            <li class="active" aria-selected="true">
                <asp:Literal
                    Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'
                    runat="server" />
            </li>
        </CurrentNodeTemplate>
        <NodeTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:HyperLink
                    ID="lnkPage"
                    Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'
                    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'
                    ToolTip='<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                    runat="server" />
            </li>
        </NodeTemplate>
    </my:NakedSiteMapPath>
</ol>
```

Comment: Question from an ASP noob: how do register my:NakedSiteMapPath so that you can use it in an .aspx?

Answer (score -1):

The best option for this is to convert the SiteMapPath to use Templates.

In the `<NodeTemplate>` you can place `<li>` elements with the format you need.
In the `<PathSeparatorTemplate>` you can place the separator.

Wrapp the SiteMapPath control with the `<ul>` tags and that should do it.

Example:

```
 <ul class="breadcrumb">
  <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" PathSeparator="" runat="server">
   <NodeTemplate>
    <li>
     <a href='<%# Eval("url") %>' title='<%# Eval("description") %>'><%# Eval("title") %></a>
    </li>
   </NodeTemplate>
   <PathSeparatorTemplate>
     <span class="divider">/</span>
   </PathSeparatorTemplate>
  </asp:SiteMapPath>
</ul>
```

This is excelent option when using Bootstrap and ASP.NET

Comment: Wouldn't that put a `span` in between each list element? `ul` elements may only contain `li` elements.

Comment: Yeah, it actually still puts the spans in, although they are now containing the li's. -1 because this does really not solve the OP's question.